# Why won't detachEvent fire in IE < 9?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, events

I've setup the simplest of simple event handler functions. Everything works dandy, except `events.remove()` in IE < 9. So, in other words, everything works great except removing events in versions of IE that utilize `.detachEvent()`.

I have been testing on IETester and VirtualBox, running Windows XP with IE8.

```
events = {
    add: (function () {
        if (document.documentElement.addEventListener) {
            return function (elm, type, func) {
                elm.addEventListener(type, func, false);
            };
        } else if (document.documentElement.attachEvent) {
            return function (elm, type, func) {
                elm.attachEvent('on' + type, function () {
                    func.call(elm, window.event);
                });
                elm = null; //clean up possible memory leaks?
            };
        }
    }()),
    remove: (function () {
        if (document.documentElement.removeEventListener) {
            return function (elm, type, func) {
                elm.removeEventListener(type, func, false);
            };
        } else if (document.documentElement.detachEvent) {
            return function (elm, type, func) {
                elm.detachEvent('on' + type, function () {
                    func.call(elm, window.event);
                });
                elm = null; //clean up possible memory leaks?
            };
        }
    }())
};
```

[Here is a (weird) fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wGcC8/5/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're trying to detach with a different function than the one that was bound.

The fact that they're both anonymous functions doesn't matter. They're two different function objects.

Comment: I need more sleep 'sigh + face palm' Thank You!